# Invalid index 3, size is 2

Tags: java, android

for some reason im getting this error, here is a shortened version of the error exception. i tired to provide as much detail as possible, but i don't really know how to deal with this problem :(

```
09-16 19:39:18.404  15774-15774/com.spizer.mizer2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.spizer.mizer2, PID: 15774
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spizer.mizer2/com.spizer.mizer2.DifficultyMenu}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.spizer.mizer2.DifficultyMenu.prepareListData(DifficultyMenu.java:187)
        at com.spizer.mizer2.DifficultyMenu.onCreate(DifficultyMenu.java:43)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6295)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

and the here is my code for the class

```
package com.spizer.mizer2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DifficultyMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

/** calls to make the class ProblemSelector usable in this class **/
ProblemSelector PS = new ProblemSelector();

private int T1;
private int T2;
private int T3;
private int T4;

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_difficulty_menu);

    // get the list view
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // List view Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // List view Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // List view Group collapsed listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // List view on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            /** converts the selected number in the expandable list to a usable integer variable **/
            if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("AdditionDifficulty")) {
                String St1 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int AddDiff = Integer.parseInt(St1);
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("SubtractionDifficulty")) {
                String St2 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int SubDiff = Integer.parseInt(St2);
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("MultiplicationDifficulty")) {
                String St3 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int MultiDIff = Integer.parseInt(St3);
            }
            else if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition).equals("DivisionDifficulty")) {
                String St4 = listDataHeader.get(childPosition);
                int DivisDiff = Integer.parseInt(St4);
            }
//                else {
//                    /** public static int e("DifficultyMenu.class", "could     not parse a group position when user selected a field"); **/
//                }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

    // Adding child data
    if(PS.AddProb) { listDataHeader.add("AdditionDifficulty"); }
    if(PS.SubProb) { listDataHeader.add("SubtractionDifficulty"); }
    if(PS.MultiProb) { listDataHeader.add("MultiplicationDifficulty"); }
    if(PS.DivisProb) { listDataHeader.add("DivisionDifficulty"); }

    /** this removes fields that the user has not selected to practice **/
    if(!PS.AddProb) { listDataHeader.remove("AdditionDifficulty"); }
    if(!PS.SubProb) { listDataHeader.remove("SubtractionDifficulty"); }
    if(!PS.MultiProb) { listDataHeader.remove("MultiplicationDifficulty"); }
    if(!PS.DivisProb) { listDataHeader.remove("DivisionDifficulty"); }

    // Adding child data
    List<String> AdditionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T1 < 21) {
            String S1 = Integer.toString(T1);
            AdditionDifficulty.add(S1);
            T1++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> SubtractionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T2 < 21) {
            String S2 = Integer.toString(T2);
            SubtractionDifficulty.add(S2);
            T2++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> MultiplicationDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T3 < 21) {
            String S3 = Integer.toString(T3);
            MultiplicationDifficulty.add(S3);
            T3++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    List<String> DivisionDifficulty = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        if (T4 < 21) {
            String S4 = Integer.toString(T4);
            DivisionDifficulty.add(S4);
            T4++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    /** this draws out the Expandable lists **/
    if(PS.AddProb) { listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), AdditionDifficulty); }
    if(PS.SubProb) { listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), SubtractionDifficulty); }
    if(PS.MultiProb) { listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), MultiplicationDifficulty); }
    if(PS.DivisProb) { listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), DivisionDifficulty); }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_difficulty_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: it's `listDataHeader.get(3)` but you only added 2 things (valid indices 0..1)

Comment: what do you mean i only added 2 things

Comment: The error says  that you try to read the 4th element in a list of 2 things. Your list does  not contain what you expect.

Comment: Have you found the problem?

Answer (score 0):

*This is a comment, not an answer, but I want to format the code.*

Isn't this:

```
while (true) {
    if (T1 < 21) {
        String S1 = Integer.toString(T1);
        AdditionDifficulty.add(S1);
        T1++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Better written as this:

```
for (; T1 < 21; T1++) {
    AdditionDifficulty.add(Integer.toString(T1));
}
```

Not sure why `T1` is a field, since the only code that ever uses it is this code.

Also note that field names should be in `camelCase`.

So if you remove the field `T1`, the code becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
    AdditionDifficulty.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
```